# cannot access to tomcat javascript folder

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, tomcat

I'm deploying my webapp to tomcat instalation directory with path standard (using maven war). The problem is that I have a javascript folder in webapp path and from the browser i cannot access. I already checked if the files are created to the right folder and they are there!

If i try to run on the browser

```
http://localhost:8080/standard/js/jquery-1.8.3.js
```

gives to me the "404 - Page not found" error.

If I put the js folder in the Root directory (instead of standard directory) everything works.

Is there any config I should change or something to do??

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `jquery-1.8.3.js` into **standard/js** subfolder and add following mapping in your `web.xml`

```
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```